# return back to previous screen with back button

Tags: android

when my app starts it says to Login if you don't login you can register 
in the register screen if you press back btn you don't turn back to login but the app is closing. any ideas?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Setting"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".History"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name=".Fall_test"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Examples"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Too many `finish()` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start register activity like

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
this.finish(); OR LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

Just remove the below one if you used it

```
this.finish(); OR LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

and just start RegisterActivity like this

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

When you press back button inside RegisterActivity it will get you back to LoginActivity.

Comment: Remove `this.finish();` line see above answer

Answer (score 0):

You are finishing / destroying your activity when you're moving to another activity. When you go from one actity to another, the old activity is reserved in a stack. And when you press back button, it's popped back from the stack. So, if you finish the old one while moving to the new one, the activity won't be reserved in the stack, thus you are being forced to exit the app as there's no activity on the stack.